# Excel generator from mysql to sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, excel, sqlsrv

I have recently converted from mysql database to SQL server 2012. I have been working on converting my excel generator for over a week, but having some few issues to find equivalent functions from mysql to sqlsrv (which I am using in php to communicate to my sql server). I will first show the mysql version, which works perfect:

```
$sql = "
SELECT measurements.title as Maling, routines.value as Verdi, DATE_FORMAT(routines.date, '%d/%m/%Y') as Dato, routines.time as Tid, pools.name as Basseng, emps.user_name as Ansatt
FROM routines, measure_routine, measurements, pools, emps
WHERE routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
AND measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
AND (measurements.title  Like 'T_%') AND measure_routine.pool_id=pools.id AND routines.emp_id=emps.id 
ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time";

$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   

//execute query 

$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
$reals=array();

//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    $type = mysql_field_type($result,$i);
    echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
    if ($type == "real")
    {
        $reals[] = $i;
    }
}

print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != ""){
            if (in_array($j, $reals)){
                $schema_insert .= str_replace(".",",","$row[$j]").$sep;
            } else {
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            }
        }
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
}
```

This is the SQL srv version, I have only changed the connection and mysql to sqlsrv functions. I have some issue with the `mysql_field_type`and `mysql_field_name` and found that `sqlsrv_field_metadata` holds the values of name and type:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT tasks.title as Oppgaver, routines.value as Verdi, DATE_FORMAT(routines.date, '%d/%m/%Y') as Dato, routines.time as Tid, emps.user_name as Ansatt
    FROM routines, task_routine, tasks, emps
    WHERE routines.id = task_routine.routine_id
    AND task_routine.task_id = tasks.id
    AND (tasks.title  Like 'C_%') AND routines.emp_id=emps.id 
    ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time";
  }


 $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . sqlsrv_error(). "<br>" . sqlsrv_errno()); 


$file_ending = "xls";
$reals=array();
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields


$metaData = sqlsrv_field_metadata($result);

for ($i = 0; $i < $metaData; $i++) {
   $type = $metaData[$i]["Type"];
   echo $metaData[$i]["Name"] . "\t";
   if ($type === SQL_REAL) {
      $reals[] = $i;
   }
}


print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
while($row = sqlsrv_num_rows($result))
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<sqlsrv_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != ""){
            if (in_array($j, $reals)){
                $schema_insert .= str_replace(".",",","$row[$j]").$sep;
            } else {
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            }
        }
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";

}
```

Comment: Why can't you use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function?

Comment: And a CSV file is __not__ an Excel file, it is simply a file that Excel is capable of importing

Comment: @MarkBaker the excel-generator worked very well in mysql so was just looking to convert the code to sqlsrv.

Comment: What's the problem? I don't see any mention of an error...

Comment: Sorry! Right now it just loads and when it finally generates the excel and I open it the excel crashes. I dont know if it goes in a loop or something.